# UseEffect: why is fetching data considered a side-effect but not accessing window.location?

Tags: reactjs

I always thought of a side-effect as a read or write operation that is performed while rendering a functional component, and that accesses resources outside of those provided as props. Sort of like the definition of a pure function.

So when I needed to read window.location, I figured it had to be in a useEffect. Turns out the linter doesn't require that window.location be a dependency, so I guess it's ok to access window directly. This means my mental model of a React side-effect is wrong... But why?

If merely fetching data (which is a read operation) is considered a side-effect, then why isn't window.location?

So now I'm wondering, are functional components actually not really pure? Are they only "write pure" but not "read pure"?

Answer (score 0):

How the `useEffect` or any other memoizing hooks(`useCallback`, `useMemo`,...) work  works is:

1. Component re-renders
2. The dependency list is looked through to detect changes in any of them
3. If a change is detected, the function inside the useEffect is called

The issue with `window.location` or any other outer scope variables is that they do not initiate a component re-render to begin with.

This is the exact message on ESLint

> Outer scope values like 'window.location.href' aren't valid
> dependencies because mutating them doesn't re-render the component

And to answer your question, yes and no.
According [this article](https://blog.logrocket.com/what-are-react-pure-functional-components/#:%7E:text=A%20React%20component%20is%20considered,are%20treated%20as%20pure%20components.) :

> A React component is considered pure if it renders the same output for
> the same state and props

So if you add a dependency to an outer scope variable like `window` in your component, you can't call that component pure anymore.